# Need suggestion for open source tools to simulate I/O delay for files in a directory on ubuntu-20.04

Tags: linux, open-source, python, ubuntu, server

Need suggestion for open source tools to simulate I/O delay for files in a directory on ubuntu-20.04. So lets say I create a directory /delay_dir, then any process trying to read/write to files under /delay_dir should experience specified delay. Lets say I specify 2 seconds, then any process reading/writing to a file should get 2 second delay only for the files under /delay_dir.

I tried using scylladb/charybdefs by cloning https://github.com/scylladb/charybdefs but it works fine only for ubuntu-18 and centos-7 and centos-8. I want to run it for ubuntu-20.04, ubuntu-22.04. Any other tool easy to use would be appreciated too.

Answer (score 1):

One solution I see is setting up a VM to that hosts a shared drive via samba or similar and then limit then bandwidth.

Dedicated tools are:

- [fio](https://linux.die.net/man/1/fio)
- [blktrace](https://linux.die.net/man/8/blktrace)
- [btreplay](https://linux.die.net/man/8/btreplay)

but they are not simpler to use per

Comment: I tried using fio but it didn't work. Will try others too. Thanks